# delete old and create new ec2 instance on every terraform apply

Tags: python, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

we are using terraform to create and setup ec2 instances , where in startup script we are cloning the other repo and starting the process from that.  (assume process : process A)

problem is when we make code  changes to this process , and now run our terraform plan .apply it does not detect any changes.

we are looking for solution that for every terraform apply , it should create old instance and create new instance so that it will freshy clone all new changes everytime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General remark: In general I believe this is not along the lines Terraform is intended to use.

Yet. I think there's a solution to your problem:

Use [the `terraform taint` command](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/taint.html) against the EC2 instance before your `apply`, e.g.

```
terraform taint aws_instance.my_not_so_precious_instance
terraform apply
```

Comment: as per the question this is so true solution . but due to some company convention we can not use it , but do u aware of any attribute which can make this instance to delete and create on terraform apply.

Comment: I am not aware.